# How to hide sensitive variables from datasource ina a local-exec provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to initialize a database using a docker image with a local provider.

```
resource "null_resource" "db_setup" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {

    command = <<EOT
        docker run \
        -e DB_CONNECTION="mysql" \
        -e DB_HOST=${module.mysql_others.endpoint} \
        -e DB_DATABASE=${data.aws_ssm_parameter.DATABASE.value} \
        -e DB_USERNAME=${data.aws_ssm_parameter.USERNAME.value} \
        -e DB_PASSWORD=${data.aws_ssm_parameter.PASSWORD.value} \
        random_docker_image:latest \
        ./database_seed
    EOT        

  }
}
```

I am getting all the comand in clear text when I terraform apply it.
Is there any way of avoid it?

Comment: Have you read this? https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/sensitive-variables

Comment: yes, but I can't find a way to use it in this scenario
I can't do somethin like....


`variable "db_password" {
  type      = string
  sensitive = true
}

db_password = data.aws_ssm_parameter.MYSQL_BK_PUBLIC_WEB_PASSWORD.value`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sensitive` function with locals to "mark" variable as sensitive.

```
locals {
  sensitive_db_password = sensitive(data.aws_ssm_parameter.PASSWORD.value)
}

resource "null_resource" "db_setup" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
            docker run \
        -e DB_CONNECTION="mysql" \
        -e DB_HOST=${module.mysql_others.endpoint} \
        -e DB_DATABASE=${data.aws_ssm_parameter.DATABASE.value} \
        -e DB_USERNAME=${data.aws_ssm_parameter.USERNAME.value} \
        -e DB_PASSWORD=${local.sensitive_db_password} \
        random_docker_image:latest \
        ./database_seed
    EOT
  }
}
```

Output will be suppressed.

Documentation : https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/sensitive